# Column SUM with "min-max" cell format

Tags: google-sheets, sum, max, min

I'm trying to make two SUMs on the same column.

Here's my columns:

```
|  1-2  |  1    |
|  2    |  2-3  |
|  1    |  5    |
|-------|-------|
|  4    |  8    | Sum 1 that take the "min" value of each cells
|  5    |  9    | Sum 2 that take the "max" value of each cells
```

Sum 1 Column 1 : 1 + 2 + 1 = 4
Sum 2 Column 1 : 2 + 2 + 1 = 5

The cells notation is either {num} which is an absolute value, or {min}-{max} which is the min and max value

This is to create some work timing estimations and we would like to have this "min-max" concept. We have already something with split columns, but it will be more comfortable to keep 1 column with 2 possible values in each cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the min:

```
=ArrayFormula(SUM(--(IFERROR(LEFT(A1:A3,FIND("-",A1:A3)-1),A1:A3))))
```

For the Max:

```
=ArrayFormula(SUM(--(IFERROR(RIGHT(A1:A3,len(A1:A3)-FIND("-",A1:A3)),A1:A3))))
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect man, thanks a lot it's exactly what we need :)
Cheers and thanks again :)